# Why does root own the dot dot ".." directory?

Tags: permissions, directory

I've been using Linux for ages - I practically live in it, but I've never actually thought to ask why root always owns the `..` directory.

If you `chmod` the totality of a subdirectory structure to some other user root still owns `..`.

Under the hood, why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`..` is the parent directory, so whoever own that owns `..`. If you run

```
ls -ld ..
```

in a subdirectory of your home directory, you should see that `..`’s owner is yourself:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls -ld ..
```

Changing a hierarchy’s owner won’t change `..`’s owner (looking from the top of the changed hierarchy) because `..` is outside of the changed hierarchy.

In your own home directory, you’ll see root as the owner of `..` because `..` is typically `/home`, and that’s owned by root:

```
cd
ls -lid .. /home
```

(you’ll see that both have the same inode number).

Comment: lol I'm just bad. That's super obvious.